# How to run psql on Mac OS X?

Tags: postgresql, installation, psql, mac-os-x

I installed PostgreSQL on a computer with Mac OS X using the [One click installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx). Then I try to access PostgreSQL using the `psql` command, but it doesn't seem to be available.

I get this message:

```
psql
-bash: psql: command not found
```

Do I have to install something more? Or how can I configure PostgreSQL so I can use it on my computer?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Appears "the way" to install the client, if you want to use hombrew, is:

```
brew install postgresql@15
```

(you need to specify the version after @) then `psql` (the client command line) will now be available to you (it also installs a local Postgres server/database, but you don't have to use that if all you want is the client).

Apparently there's also a 'wrapper' to the `psql` command to make it more "user friendly" also available via [homebrew](https://www.pgcli.com/install) (`brew install pgcli`) in case interesting.  `Pgcli is a command line interface for Postgres with auto-completion and syntax highlighting.`

Another option is to install the `libpq` homebrew package, but it doesn't get in your PATH.

```
brew install libpq
```

So follow the instructions it says after install out to add it to your PATH, or `brew link --force libpq` or add a [symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689589/32453).

Comment: Apparently there's no way of using `psql` without installing the whole database engine. I found `pgcli` more convenient for when for instance you want to have all your services dockerized. Way to go @rogerdpack!

Comment: If all you need is the cli, I'd recommend having a look at the @luril [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258890/228243) below.

Comment: Note about these comments suggesting pgcli to avoid installing the whole database engine - the `pgcli` docs state that installing pgcli will also install postgresql if it doesn't exist yet. https://www.pgcli.com/install

Comment: This answer no longer works because you're required to specify the version now-a-days. The solution is `brew install postgresql@15` or whatever the newest version is.

Comment: Want to add a note here and say that if you target a specific version like this, it will not add the executables to `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/bin` and therefore you will not be able to use the commands until you add them to your PATH.

Answer (score 56):

Locate the psql binary. (In a terminal, run `locate psql | grep /bin`, and make note of the path. (In my case, it's `/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/`, as it was installed using MacPorts.)

Then, edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home folder (e.g. `mate -w ~/.bash_profile` assuming you've textmate), and add the needed line so it's in your path, e.g.:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/:$PATH
```

After having saved the file, read the file (`. ~/.bash_profile`) or open a new terminal, and type `psql`.

Comment: Thanks, my path to psql was `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/psql` and I created a `.bash_profile` file as you suggested and it works great.

Comment: @Jonas: +1 Your comment should really go into a separate answer and should be the accepted answer, because this is the default location when installing Postgres on a Mac!

Comment: The locate command didn't work initially for me, I had to first run `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` then wait for the `find` process to finish

Comment: also had to create the .bash_profile file, mac noob here! ;-) working now though, thanks!

Comment: better `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/:$PATH`

Comment: I installed postgresql 9.6 via brew and my psql was at `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.6/9.6.6/bin/psql`

Comment: Another option, if you don't want to mess with your PATH settings is to simply add a symlink to a well known location, which is already in your path. For me that would be `ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql`

Comment: If you are using zsh instead of bash, does the export statement have to go in the .zshrc?

Answer (score 16):

I strongly recommend using [`Postgres.app`](http://postgresapp.com) from the Heroku team, which is also supported by them!

It has a menubar icon and the menu has a `psql` item:

[image: Postgres.app menubar icon menu]

You will also find `psql` included here if you want the same version of that as the server (path may vary by version):

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
```

If you want, you can add this path to your startup script to execute `psql` directly:

```
PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

**CAVEAT!** AFAIK, `Postgres.app` doesn't support connections via Unix sockets (I am not sure what this is...), and supports only TCP/IP connections. So don't panic if you fail to connect there from some other programs.

Comment: The latest documentation http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html lists the path as `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: Actually comment turns out to be a better answer :)

Comment: better `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/:$PATH`

Comment: I looked but couldn't find any relation between `Heroku team` and the app. Can you share how are they connected?

Answer (score 15):

Install `just client` with `brew`:

```
brew install pgcli
```

then link it:

```
brew link --force libpq
```

as output you will get the path to `psql`:

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

to find this path again:

```
brew info libpq
```

Comment: It is not `just client`, the documentation says: "If you're on macOS you can install it via Homebrew. Just be aware that this will install postgresql if you don't already have it."

Answer (score 5):

According to the [installation guide](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide) after the installation has finished there should be shortcuts for StackBuilder, pgAdmin3 and **psql** in the Application folder of Postgres:

> You will also find additional shortcuts to run pgAdmin, the psql command line interface and to access the PostgreSQL documentation.

If there are such shortcuts check where the psql's one is pointing.

Comment: Thanks, this aslo worked. I hadn't seen that documentation, only the documentation on `postgresql.org`.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install libpq    
brew link --force libpq
```

I followed the below walkthrough and it worked.
https://blog.timescale.com/tutorials/how-to-install-psql-on-mac-ubuntu-debian-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I installed PostgresQL with the installer from https://www.postgresql.org/download/
The psql executable was put into /Library/PostgreSQL/14/bin. I added that to my path.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [EDB Installer](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), but during the installation choose to install only the Command Line Tools
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `brew` and installing the whole server is overkill, I found that pgAdmin (the GUI app) provides you with a psql cli.  Right click the database and choose `PSQL Tool` to open up a session.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda similar to @inyourcorner, but i had to double-click on the database... see image: (on mac) (and thanks for leading me there!)...
-Click on elephant (postgres) icon in upper toolbar
-Double-click on the database to work on
-Takes you to terminal with prompt to enter psql commands

[image: How to enter psql commands on mac]

Answer (score -1):

To highlight the comment:
`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` – the folder of `psql`

Comment: please add more explantion, you have lesss than the comment