# After fresh install getting `psql: command not found`

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, installation, mac-os-x

I downloaded and installed [PostgreSQL and PostGIS from KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres) for my OS X 10.10 install. When I run `psql` I get,

```
bash: psql: command not found
```

According to the site [How to run psql on Mac OS X?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/how-to-run-psql-on-mac-os-x) it gets installed into `/Library/PostgreSQL`. There is no file there.

Comment: I've deleted irelevant and incorrect information, if `locate` didn't work your locatedb was out of date. and PostGIS has nothing to do with the PATH or PostgreSQL. Also, in the future, use brew. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the `README` included in the dmg file, postgres binaries are installed in `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/`. You should add these lines in your `~/.bashrc` :

```
export PSQL_DIR=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/
export PATH="$PSQL_DIR:$PATH"
```

Update your environment with `source ~/.bashrc` or run a new shell and `psql` should be available.

Comment: Would that be the command for a mac as well?

Comment: For sure, i'm using these on my Mac (;

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charme. Another questions. It seems that I have to do the `export ...` every time I restart my computer. Is there a way to do it permanently?

Comment: Create a new file in your home directory named .bashrc and add these lines in this files. Your terminal will then load run these lines each time your open a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

It appears your problem is regarding setting Environment Variables correctly. After installation, the command psql won't work because you need to set the correct PATH to this command in your Environment variables file - which will differ a little according to your version.

I just wanted to add a comment here for future inquiries.

I'm working on a MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 and the current default terminal is using a SHELL called 'zsh'.

I used the following command from the terminal:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and adding the following line:

```
export PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/11/bin:$PATH"
```

control X (to quit) and S (to Save) and ENTER (previous filename)
Please note that this path above will depend on your PostgreSQL version - I would recommend you to look this information on your documentation / website.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS Big Sur:

Before installing zsh, bash was working perfectly fine.
After switching from bash to zsh I experienced the infamous: `command not found`.
I realize that my PATH was empty for this particular shell.

in the terminal:

```
env
```

then copy the PATH line(s) (could be a multi line value!):

```
PATH=/....
```

and in your personnal directory: /Users/your_name/ you should find the .zshrc file. At the end of this file put:

```
export PATH=/...
```

quit your terminal, launch it again and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

**macOS Monterey && postgres 14**

`export PSQL_DIR=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin`

`export PATH="$PSQL_DIR:$PATH"`

Comment: +1 I had a mentee that had this issue.  This was the only place we could find the bin.  Thank you for that help.  This answer could be improved by including directions on how to add these commands to the .zshrc, .bashrc, and .bash_profiles files so that psql will be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a Windows user habit but the key step is to restart the terminal after executing this command to configure your $PATH to use the included command line tools:

```
# sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```